# How do I 'activate' the Catnip Processing once researched?

Tags: kittens-game

I researched Catnip Processing but I do not notice a difference when I try to process into wood. Is this currently bugged? I also did not notice any new buildings or sciences to unlock related to it. The wiki suggests "Brewing" but that is not present.

Comment: Catnip Processing used to be called Brewing; the wiki is out of date and doesn't reflect the updated name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catnip Processing unlocks Catnip Enrichment in the workshop. You have to build a workshop before you can get Catnip Enrichment. Building the workshop requires that you have researched Construction and have enough wood and minerals.

Comment: I worded it poorly but this is what I was looking for. Why it seemed the enrichment was not available. Thank you!